# Is there a way to share authorship of an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, accepted-answer

In the question [What visual wave behavior help to tell...](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2860/what-visual-wave-behaviour-help-to-tell-if-a-tide-is-going-in-or-out), the current accepted answer was first drafted by me, but IRO-bot provided a very good complement to the answer. The point is that, it should be considered a collaborative answer and IRO-bot should be able to get as much credit for the answer as I do. Is there such feature? Can such a feature be added?

Answer (score 3):

You can mark this answer as Community Wiki. What this does is allow 100+ reputation users to edit it anytime. It also gives the original author (you) no reputation.

For more information, see [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts):

> ### Why have Community Wiki posts?
>
> One of the goals of the website is to be a continually evolving source
> of good information.  Community wiki posts help enhance the *wiki*
> aspect of the site.
>
> ### How do Community Wiki posts work?
>
> Community wiki posts work by transferring ownership of the post from
> the original author to the community.  They make the post easier to
> edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not
> contribute to any user's reputation.
>
> Some of the key features are:
>
> - Community wiki posts are owned by the Community User <sup>1</sup>, not by any individual user.
> - A much lower reputation (**100** instead of **2000**) is needed to edit a community wiki post. <sup>2</sup>
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
> - Accepting an answer marked as community wiki [does not affect its author's reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145935/152859).
> - Bounties awarded to answer marked as community wiki give reputation as usual.
> - The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
> - The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.
> - The original author still receives notifications for edits or comments on the post.

To make your answer community wiki, there should be a checkbox in the right-hand corner when editing that says 'community wiki'. Just check this checkbox and save the edit.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you get some little reputation for the edit. I think a feature request about sharing reputation updates for edited answers and questions is a good idea. A feature description could be:

> **Shared contributions**
>
> Users can provide shares to editors of their posts to award the contributions of other users. Questions are divided in 5 shares, answers in 10 shares. By default all shares belong to the original poster. The original poster is allowed to distribute these shares freely among all editors. Each share is worth one reputation point in future upvotes. So, the editors can gain some reputation points by future upvotes, while the original poster gets fewer points. Downvotes cause reputation loss to all shareholders, without any discrimination about the numbers of shares. Editors need to accept offered shares to become an active shareholder. Additionally, one can earn badges for providing and accepting shares.

The above described feature would need to be granted and implemented.

Comment: Note that if you want to propose such a feature the place to do it is on the main meta site, MSE aka meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @casy I copied my answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244050/238658